# multiple transitive excludes not working in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to clean up my dependencies and eliminate some class collections im running into.  for some reason, my excludes aren't working.

here's my script

```
description = 'Onus Pride Collective System'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.springsource.org/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:docbook-reference-plugin:0.2.2'
    }
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'servlet', module: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
    exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j', version:'1.2.17'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core', version: '3.2.3.RELEASE'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-tx', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE'
}

configure(allprojects) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    group = 'com.onuspride'
    version = '0.0.1'

    sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources', 'src/test/java']
    test.systemProperty("java.awt.headless", "true")

    ext {
        akka = '2.2.3'
        akkaSeries = '_2.10'
        apacheLog4jVersion = '2.0-beta9'
        aspectjVersion = '1.7.2'
        cglibVersion = '2.2.2'
        commonsCodecVersion = '1.5'
        commonsDigesterVersion = '2.1'
        commonsFileuploadVersion = '1.3'
        commonsLang3Version = '3.1'
        elApiVersion = '1.0'
        fasterxmlJacksonVersion = '2.3.0'
        flexJsonVersion = '2.1'
        ginVersion = '2.0.0'
        googleAPIClient = '1.17.0-rc'
        googleAPIDrive = 'v2-rev110-1.17.0-rc'
        googleAPIOauth2 = 'v2-rev59-1.17.0-rc'
        googleJackson = '1.15.0-rc'
        guavaVersion = '14.0.1'
        guiceVersion = '3.0'
        gwtpVersion = '1.0.3'
        gwtqueryVersion = '1.3.2'
        gwtsecurityVersion = '1.2.3'
        gwtVersion = '2.5.1'
        hamcrestDateVersion = '0.9.5'
        hibernateValidator = '5.0.2.Final'
        ioSpray = '1.2.0'
        javaxServletVersion = '3.0.1'
        jedisVersion = '2.1.0'
        jettyVersion = '9.1.0.v20131115'
        jodaTimeVersion = '1.6'
        json4sVersion = '3.2.6'
        jspApiVersion = '2.1'
        jstlApiVersion = '1.2'
        jukitoVersion = '1.1'
        junitVersion = '4.11'
        lmaxDistruptorVersion = '3.2.0'
        neo4jVersion = '2.0.0'
        persistenceApiVersion = '1.0'
        scalaLangVersion = '2.10.2'
        slf4jVersion = '1.7.5'
        socialSigninTwitterVersion = '1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        springDataNeo4jVersion = '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        springDataRedis = '1.1.0.RELEASE'
        springJsResourcesVerison = '2.3.2.RELEASE'
        springJsVersion = '2.3.2.RELEASE'
        springScalaVersion = '1.0.0.RC1'
        springSecurityVersion = '3.2.0.RELEASE'
        springSocialGoogleVersion = '1.0.0.M3'
        springSocialVersion = '1.1.0.M4'
        springVersion = '3.2.6.RELEASE'
        tilesJspVersion = '2.2.2'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
        maven { url "https://repo.springsource.org/milestone" }
        //maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://gabiaxel.github.io/maven" }
        maven { url "http://download.java.net/maven/2" }
    }

}

configure(subprojects) { subproject ->

    jar {
        manifest.attributes['Implementation-Title'] = subproject.name
        manifest.attributes['Implementation-Version'] = subproject.version

        from("${rootProject.projectDir}/src/dist") {
            include "license.txt"
            include "notice.txt"
            into "META-INF"
            expand(copyright: new Date().format('yyyy'), version: project.version)
        }
    }

    javadoc {
        options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
        options.author = true
        options.header = project.name
        //options.overview = "${projectDir}/src/main/java/overview.html"
    }

    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
    }

    task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from javadoc
    }

    artifacts {
        archives sourcesJar
        archives javadocJar
    }
}

project('inclusive') {
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    sourceCompatibility=1.7
    targetCompatibility=1.7

    description = 'Common library.  This is used to tie the various systems together.'
    dependencies {
        compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaTimeVersion"
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaLangVersion"

        //compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$fasterxmlJacksonVersion"
        //compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLang3Version"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:$springSocialVersion"
    }
}

project('wisdom') {
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    //apply plugin: 'war'
    //apply plugin: 'jetty'
    sourceCompatibility=1.7
    targetCompatibility=1.7
    description = 'Common library.  This is used to tie the various systems together.'

    test.systemProperty("java.awt.headless", "true")

    dependencies {

        compile project (':inclusive')

        //compile "com.gwtplatform:gwtp-dispatch-client:$gwtpVersion"
        //compile "com.gwtplatform:gwtp-dispatch-server-spring:$gwtpVersion"
        //compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:$commonsCodecVersion"
        //compile "commons-digester:commons-digester:$commonsDigesterVersion"
        //compile "commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:$commonsFileuploadVersion"
        //compile "javax.el:el-api:$elApiVersion"
        //compile "javax.persistence:persistence-api:$persistenceApiVersion"
        //compile "javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:$jstlApiVersion"
        //compile "javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:$jspApiVersion"
        compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaTimeVersion"
        //compile "net.sf.flexjson:flexjson:$flexJsonVersion"
        //compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLang3Version"
        //compile "org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:$tilesJspVersion"

        //
        //compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidator"
        //compile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion"
        //compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:$springSecurityVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:$springSecurityVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-google:$springSocialGoogleVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-web:$springSocialVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.webflow:spring-js-resources:$springJsVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework:spring-aspects:$springVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"
        //runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.9"
        //runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5"


        //compile "cglib:cglib:$cglibVersion"
        //compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$fasterxmlJacksonVersion"
        //compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$fasterxmlJacksonVersion"
        //compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:$googleAPIClient"
        //compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:$googleAPIDrive"
        //compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:$googleAPIOauth2"
        //compile "com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:$googleJackson"
        //compile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1"
        //compile "com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.9"
        compile "com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor$akkaSeries:$akka"
        compile "com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j$akkaSeries:$akka"
        compile "io.spray:spray-can:$ioSpray"
        compile "io.spray:spray-routing:$ioSpray"
        //compile "io.spray:spray-servlet:1.2.0"
        //compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$javaxServletVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:$apacheLog4jVersion"
        compile "com.lmax:disruptor:$lmaxDistruptorVersion"

        //compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:$aspectjVersion"
        //compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:$aspectjVersion"
        //compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:$jettyVersion"
        //compile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:$jettyVersion"
        compile "org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:$json4sVersion"
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaLangVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:$springDataNeo4jVersion"
        compile "org.springframework.scala:spring-scala_2.10:$springScalaVersion"
        //compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:$springDataRedis"
        //compile "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion"
        //compile "redis.clients:jedis:$jedisVersion"
        //compile "uk.co.modular-it:hamcrest-date:$hamcrestDateVersion"
        //compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j', version: "$neo4jVersion"
        //compile group: 'org.neo4j.app', name: 'neo4j-server', version: "$neo4jVersion", classifier: 'static-web'

        //testCompile "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1"
        //testCompile "com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit$akkaSeries:$akka"
        //testCompile "io.spray:spray-testkit:$ioSpray"
        //testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
        //testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
        //testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    }

    tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
        scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
    }
}

configure(rootProject) {
    description = 'Spring Social'

    apply plugin: 'docbook-reference'

    reference {
        ext.sourceDir = file('src/reference/docbook')
    }

    // don't publish the default jar for the root project
    configurations.archives.artifacts.clear()

    dependencies { // for integration tests
    }

    task api(type: Javadoc) {
        group = 'Documentation'
        description = 'Generates aggregated Javadoc API documentation.'
        title = "${rootProject.description} ${version} API"
        options.memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
        options.author = true
        options.header = rootProject.description
        options.overview = 'src/api/overview.html'
        options.links(
                'http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.5/connector'
        )
        source subprojects.collect { project ->
            project.sourceSets.main.allJava
        }
        destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "api")
        classpath = files(subprojects.collect { project ->
            project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
        })
        maxMemory = '1024m'
    }

    task docsZip(type: Zip) {
        group = 'Distribution'
        classifier = 'docs'
        description = "Builds -${classifier} archive containing api and reference " +
                "for deployment at static.springframework.org/spring-social/docs."

        from('src/dist') {
            include 'changelog.txt'
        }

        from (api) {
            into 'api'
        }

        from (reference) {
            into 'reference'
        }
    }

    task schemaZip(type: Zip) {
        group = 'Distribution'
        classifier = 'schema'
        description = "Builds -${classifier} archive containing all " +
                "XSDs for deployment at static.springframework.org/schema."

        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            def Properties schemas = new Properties();

            subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                it.path.endsWith('META-INF/spring.schemas')
            }?.withInputStream { schemas.load(it) }

            for (def key : schemas.keySet()) {
                def shortName = key.replaceAll(/http.*schema.(.*).spring-.*/, '$1')
                assert shortName != key
                File xsdFile = subproject.sourceSets.main.resources.find {
                    it.path.endsWith(schemas.get(key))
                }
                assert xsdFile != null
                into (shortName) {
                    from xsdFile.path
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task distZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: [docsZip, schemaZip]) {
        group = 'Distribution'
        classifier = 'dist'
        description = "Builds -${classifier} archive, containing all jars and docs, " +
                "suitable for community download page."

        ext.baseDir = "${project.name}-${project.version}";

        from('src/dist') {
            include 'readme.txt'
            include 'license.txt'
            include 'notice.txt'
            into "${baseDir}"
            expand(copyright: new Date().format('yyyy'), version: project.version)
        }

        from(zipTree(docsZip.archivePath)) {
            into "${baseDir}/docs"
        }

        from(zipTree(schemaZip.archivePath)) {
            into "${baseDir}/schema"
        }

        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            into ("${baseDir}/libs") {
                from subproject.jar
                if (subproject.tasks.findByPath('sourcesJar')) {
                    from subproject.sourcesJar
                }
                if (subproject.tasks.findByPath('javadocJar')) {
                    from subproject.javadocJar
                }
            }
        }
    }

    artifacts {
        archives docsZip
        archives schemaZip
        archives distZip
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        description = 'Generates gradlew[.bat] scripts'
        gradleVersion = '1.4'
    }

}

class Ajc extends DefaultTask {
    Ajc() {
        logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.INFO)
    }

    @TaskAction
    def compile() {
        logger.info "Running ajc ..."

        ant.taskdef(resource: "org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: project.configurations.ajtools.asPath)
        ant.iajc(classpath: sourceSet.compileClasspath.asPath, fork: 'true', destDir: sourceSet.classesDir.absolutePath,
                source: project.sourceCompatibility,
                target: project.targetCompatibility,
                aspectPath: aspectPath.asPath, sourceRootCopyFilter: '**/*.java', showWeaveInfo: 'true', Xlint: "ignore") {
            sourceroots {
                sourceSet.java.srcDirs.each {
                    pathelement(location: it.absolutePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is it excludes the servlet-api 2.5 just fine.  but it ignores the others.  i still get logback in my dependencies (brought over from neo) and multiple versions of spring.  Whats wrong with my script?

Comment: Please trim down the build script to the relevant parts (or better, reduce it to a minimal script that exhibits the same problem), and show the output for `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency logback`.

Comment: i get `No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':compile'`.  I get the same thing when i run it for spring-core which im using all over the place.  I hate to trim the script down because its copied out of the spring builders and i'm still not sure exactly what pieces of it are doing so i'm not sure if its relevant or not.

Comment: So how do you tell that you still get logback? (Also try with `--configuration runtime`.)

Comment: because when i refresh the project in intellij, there it is.  along with multiple copies of spring.  when I dump the entire dependency tree with `gradle -q dependencies wisdom:dependencies`, there they are.  Listed as being brought over by Neo4j.  But the jar being there is really playing havoc with my slf4j config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-project build, but exclusions were only declared for the root project. Like almost all other build information, configurations are per-project. Hence, the exclusions have to be declared for `allprojects`, `subprojects`, or the specific project(s) that need them (which is likely not the root project).

Comment: Beautiful, I put it in `configure(subprojects) { subproject -> configurations.all {...}` and it worked.  thanks